Backup local Postgrsql DB and restore on Vercel
Tried explain below the reason for my question but in a nutshell:
Got a local postgresql databasse and exact copy on Vercel  (since both created by prisma migrations)
I was hoping there's a way to backup the postgrsql database on my local machine (Win 11) and restore it on Vercel (dont care about loosing data)
Total PG noob, come from the days when one backed up a ms sql database to a .bak file, remote desktop to the server and restore it there.
If you need the reason for above, that's below :
I got a MS SQL database on my local machine with tons of data I collected over the years.
I want to use this data in my NextJS14 App using Prisma and Postgresql.
I created a page where one can upload a CSV file, which then use a server action to save each record to the posgresql database.
On my local machine / database, this goes rather "quick"...maybe take 20mins.
However in prod (hosted on Vercel) it goes so slow it will take about 48hrs if it run non stop.
Not only eat this in my vercel usages (since a hobby project, i dont want to over spend) but also silly.
